# What is wrong with this for Loop syntax?

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

```
for(String.includes('Sample'))
{
    String = String.replace("Sample",' ');
}
```

This is throwing an `; expected` error, I just want the loop to remove all the samples

Comment: Do you know the [`for` loop syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)?

Comment: Are you confusing a `for` loop with an `if` statement or `while` loop?

Comment: No there are multiple Sample-Words in this string, i want the for loop to run till they are gone

Comment: use `while (String.includes("Sample")) { String = String.replace("Sample",' '); }`?

Comment: Nothing shown to loop over and `String` is a global window object Always provide a [mcve]

Comment: @FriederMüller Yeah?  And why is a `while` loop not appropriate?  While the string contains the word, remove the word.  Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `while`:

```
while (someString.includes('Sample'))
{
    someString = someString.replace('Sample', ' '); 
    // are you sure you need an empty space, btw?
}
```

... or, far better, just use regex with global flag on:

```
someString = someString.replace(/Sample/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

the for syntax for javascript is like this

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++) { some code }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems here:

The for loop in javascript needs to have this structure:

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
    code block to be executed
}
```

you can omit statements in there but the ";" is always required.

Other thing you need to be aware is you are using String as a variable, is not a reserved word but you can have issues in the future.

If you want to go thru an array or something you better use forEach.

Comment: The parts of the `for` statement are expressions, not statements.